# Facebook Graph API - Unable to post feed by app name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make an app that has permission to post on user's wall. I have got the `publish_stream` rights from the user as well as offline access just to make sure. However now when I try to post on the app's subscribers wall using:

```
$status = $facebook->api("/$user_id/feed", 'POST', array('message' => "$msg"));
```

However when I do that then instead of posting on subscriber's wall from app it posts from the subscriber's name.

For example, let's say my app name is `MyApp` and I have a subscriber name `Sub1`. If, from my interface, I try to post a message 'Test message', it posts on `Sub1`'s wall not by name of `MyApp` but instead the user himself. Can anyone tell me what might be wrong?

Comment: Well', this is preatty strange :) are u sure u'r using the right access_token (the one associated with `MyApp`)?

Comment: do you have an access_token ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: Well I didn't have access token before but now I ve it n it doesn't seem to work at all.. getSession doesn't work for me even I am using the latest code so I got access token using:
http://kartiklad.com/oauth-2-0-and-graph-api-for-facebook-canvas-applications/
Can you tell if this seems a valid token? "135982363143562|vBdRY6_oxTgSzI-6hGmPyiHnu7A"

After getting access token I'm following:
http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/

but it gives:
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.